# ODE and linear substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a hard time solving the following differential equation:
$$\dot{x}=\frac{1}{t+2x}$$

I tried introducing $z = t+2x$, and so $\dot{z}=1+2\dot{x}$, and I got the following:
$$\dot{z}=\frac{2}{z}+1$$
Which is also not in a known form. What am I missing?

Comment: $\dfrac{z}{2+z}\ dz=dt$

Comment: This *is* a known form !

Answer (score 0):

You have a separable differential equation $$ \dot {z}=\frac {z+2}{z}$$

$$ \int \frac {zdz}{z+2}=\int dt$$